# SignalR demo not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget, signalr

I'm following this quick tutorial on getting a SignalR project started, and in my Hub class, I have the following

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace MvcApplication8.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void BroadcastMessage(string message)
        {
            Clients.writeMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        chat.writeMessage = function(msg) {
            $("#messages").append("<li>" + msg + "</li>");
        };
        $("#buttonSubmit").click(function () {
            chat.broadcastMessage($("#txtInput").val());
        });
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
```

However I'm getting a compile time error saying:

> 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubConnectionContext' does not contain
>   a definition for 'writeMessage' and no extension method 'writeMessage'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubConnectionContext' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Where went wrong?

I installed SignalR into my project from http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.signalr
using the package manager console "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Pre"

Comment: I have edited my post to include the actual message

Wow, a vote down just for that? telling me that would've been sufficient. 

I'm getting a compile time error, do I really need to explicitly ask "how do i get rid of the compile time error?"

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the corresponding client-function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.chat;
        chat.writeMessage = function (message) {
            $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
        };
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the following packages installed:

- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.AspNet
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.Common

Answer (score 0):

Try update NuGet Packages. TOOLS > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution, in left part of window click to "Updates", in the central part of windows you get the list of packages to be updated, then click "Install" over the package do you like to get the latest version. I update all: JQuery, Json.NET, Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR, Microsoft.Owin

After update the packages to latest version (SignalR Currently 2.2.0) you can compile. Don´t forget update references in "StockTicker.html", in my case after update this look like:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
```